# Parsing a jQuery.ajax error response message

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am posting data from one ASP.NET page to another via jQuery ajax call in a form of JSON.

I am simulating the situation, where is get an error on ajax call. I get a response message in case of an error and I need to assign this html to an element on the page.

Here is what I get in a message:
[image: jquery.ajax response]

I have the msg javascript variable, that, when looked up via Chrome debugger shows me that it contains info I need in `responseText`.

How do I get the value of responseText to display on the page?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In JavaScript variable names are case sensitive. In your example, you were trying to access the `responseText` field on the msg object, but you had a capital 'R'. Try this instead:

```
msg['responseText']
```

Or in much better style:

```
msg.responseText
```

Answer (score 2):

Since its an Object use the dot notation to access it like xhr.responseText

```
error: function(xhr, status, error) {

  var err = eval("(" + xhr.responseText + ")");

  alert(err.Message);

}
```

Comment: My first temptation was to down vote you for using eval...but this works really well!!  :-)  Thanks for this answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can see in the code just under your mouse pointer - only with "r", not capital "R":

```
msg['responseText']
```

Answer (score 1):

```
<div id='error'></div>
```

assume that u got error in `msg`

```
$('#error').html(msg.responseText)
```